# What performance benefit does dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier provide?

Tags: ios, performance, uitableview

I was thinking - dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier still has to instantiate a new cell and depending on the dimensions of the instantiated cell it has to recompute the layout. So how actually does this dequeuing help?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The whole point is that it doesn't have to instantiate a new cell. It reuses existing cells that have scrolled off the screen. This avoids a lot of memory allocations, which are often the major performance bottleneck in a system. For NIB-based cells (including in Storyboards), it avoids significant deserialization time. In most cases the layout will also already be correct.

That said, the impact of allocating new cells has become less important as the iPhone has gotten faster. Today, you can often generate brand new cells without any major performance impact, but on an iPhone 3G cell reuse was absolutely critical to smooth scrolling.

Comment: still hard to believe instantiating a new UITableViewCell incurrs such a performance oevrhead :) thanks

Comment: Absolutely; there is a lot of of work in Foundation devoted to avoiding "real" memory allocations and deallocations because they're so expensive. It's one of the very top things you try to remove when working on high-performance code. Messing with the main heap is particularly horrible in multi-threaded code because it causes threads to block each other. There are all kinds of things that programs, frameworks, and languages do to try to improve on this, but as long as we use a heap for storing data, it's a problem.

Comment: could you please provide some more examples, where Foundation is avoiding "real" memory allocs ?

Comment: and/or could you point me at some interesting sources for further reading?

Comment: Sure: https://cocoawithlove.com/2010/05/look-at-how-malloc-works-on-mac.html is a nice intro to some of the low-level details around `malloc`. More depth comes from the always-informative ridiculous_fish: http://ridiculousfish.com/blog/posts/36.html Tagged pointers (https://mikeash.com/pyblog/friday-qa-2012-07-27-lets-build-tagged-pointers.html) are an incredibly important tool for avoiding small memory allocations. (And Mike's whole category: https://mikeash.com/pyblog/?tag=memory) Less related, but I also highly recommend http://www.friday.com/bbum/category/science/technology/objective-c/

Comment: Internally, Foundation/AppKit/UIKit also cache a lot of things and provides singletons to avoid recreating them. For example, when there aren't tagged pointers, small values (-1...12) of `NSNumber` are singleton objects to avoid creating a new object every time you need one. (Python does this, too, BTW, for -5...256.)